# Xamarin.Forms Can't Archive because the packaging process was failed

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I clicked the archive button of Xamarin.Forms's Android Project.
Though I did many ways from any other community, github issues, but it failed.
The Settings that I already had :

1. Set The Linker Only SDK -> None
2. Set Android project's .csproj AndroidEnableProfiledAot to true
3. Set the solution configuration to release. (Any CPU)

Anyway it's archiving was failed but some strange warnings like [this](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2120) is disappeared.

But the important and serious problem is now there's failing Archive without error message.
So I can't do anything. Is there any ways to archive my Xamarin.Forms android application?

Comment: What is the versio of your Visual Studio? Could you give the details of the error message? You could follow the details in the link below. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-archiving-and-publishing-made-easy/

Comment: I solved my problem. https://manufacture.tistory.com/93 Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error occurred because of the long name which exceeded the maximum number of characters for the windows path (255 characters).

Renaming my project solved it.